Raspberry Pi 3B+ shows solid red light and no hdmi output after working previously
My 3b+ has sat for a few years covered, didn't have any dust or shorts when I looked at it. I finally decided to try using it again with the original microSD card and I can't get it to boot past the solid red light, and there's no output to HDMI. Whatever I had installed on the microSD worked perfectly back when I first did it, I think it was NOOBS. Any ideas?

Bad power supply, bad sd card, bad raspberry pi .... try new power supply, new sd card - though, it's odd the green led doesn't even flicker - perhaps it really is a dead pi - are you competent enough to measure voltages on at least the gpio pins?

Have you read the boot sticky? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151
